# Explore the series for absolute and conditional convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} k}{\sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)}} $$
I found that absolute series diverges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you *don't* have$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^kk}{\sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)}}=0,\tag1$$the series diverges. And you don't have $(1)$ because$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^kk}{\sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)}}\right\rvert=1.$$